# Запрет ввода символов в элементы структуры (p1.x)

Tags: c++

Как запретить ввод символов в консольном приложении?

Имеются две структуры: точка и прямоугольник, координаты которого задаются 2-мя точками. Правильно ли я использую *isdigit()*?

```
        while (true) {
        cout << "Координата левой верхней точки прямоугольника:" << endl << "x=";
        cin >> p1.x;
```

Comment: 1. Поле `x` сделать приватным 2. Создать функцию setX, которая устанавливает ему значение и getX для получения значения. 3. В setX добавить проверку значения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (;;) {
    std::cout << "Координата левой верхней точки прямоугольника:" << std::flush;
    if ((std::cin >> p1.x).good()) break;
    std::cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max(),'\n');
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое, а конструкция isDigit, в такой ситуации неуместна видимо?

Comment: Если очень хочется - можно самому делать то, что делает оператор `>>`, но зачем?...

Comment: Если состояние потока `good()` - значит, введено и считано число (остановка будет там, где пошло *не число*, но это может быть вводом уже следующей сущности. Если не число - сбрасываем флаг ошибки и игнорируем всю введенную строку, и начинаем заново.

Comment: @Hurry, теперь понятно, спасибо.